# Filtering mail inbox using two dates using python O365 library

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

Hi I'm trying to create a query to filter the inbox messages from a specific account using the O365 API in Python. I only managed to filter the inbox using the query helper using the on received attribute like the following:

```
       credentials=('id', 'pass')

        account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='tenantid')
        if account.authenticate():
           print('Authenticated!')
        account.connection.refresh_token()

        if('QP_FV_Mail' in diccionario['cadenaMail']):
            mailbox = account.mailbox(resource='usr1@domain.com')

        elif('ET_FV_Mail' in diccionario['cadenaMail']):
            mailbox = account.mailbox(resource='usr2@domain.com')

        query = mailbox.new_query()

        inbox=mailbox.inbox_folder()
        today = date.today()
        received_dt = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
        query = query.on_attribute('received_date_time').greater(received_dt)
        inbox=mailbox.inbox_folder()
        
        try:
            #for message in list(messages):
            for message in inbox.get_messages(limit=100,query=query):
                #do stuff
```

However I want to adjust the query filter to be in between 2 dates. Can this be done? Where can i find the documentation? The official docs only has one page with one example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the query which essentially adds another constraint (that can be bitwise) eg

```
query.chain('and').on_attribute('received_date_time').less_equal(end_dt)
```